# Filtrar datos por campos de tipo select en Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, html-select

Trabajo en Laravel 5.5 y quiero saber como puedo realizar el filtrado de datos con un select que me muestre productos dependiendo del tipo de ordenado que se le de, en este caso sería ascendente y descendente.
este es mi select

```html
ORDENADO POR:<div class="col-3" style="display:inline-block;">  <select name="ordenado" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Predeterminado</option>
                <option value="">Ascendente</option>               
                <option value="">Descendente</option>
            </select>  
        </div>
```

- en mi vista muestro los productos que tengo guardados en mi base de datos pero quiero aplicar el ordendado interactuando desde la vista.

```html
 @foreach($productos as $producto) 
<div class="blog-card">
   
      <div class="description">
        <h1>{{$producto->nombre}}</h1>
        <h2>Categoría: {{$producto->categorias['nombre']}}</h2>
        <p> {{$producto->descripcion}}</p>
      </div>
    
    </div>
     @endforeach
```

Comment: Muéstranos el código de lo que has intentado en Laravel (PHP).

Comment: En la vista muestro solo los productos así como los extraigo de la bd.

Comment: como los extraes de la BD? cual es el orden predeterminado? si ya tienes todos los datos en la vista lo mas eficiente sería ordenarlos en el frontend con js, en vez de hacer otra llamada al backend para que devuelva lo mismo ordenado de otra forma. Con Ascendente y Descendente te refieres al nombre del producto?

Comment: los extraigo de esta forma:
        $productos = Producto::where('idmarca', $marc);
el orden predeterminado sería en el orden en que fue agregado cada producto, el orden ascendente y descendente toman como referencia el nombre del producto. La consulta que se muestra es la predeterminada pero como hago para los demás, como creo el vínculo de la vista a la lista desplegable?

Answer (score 1):

> en mi vista muestro los productos que tengo guardados en mi base de datos pero quiero aplicar el ordendado interactuando desde la vista.

Si quieres aplicar el ordenado interactuando desde la vista tienes que trabajar en el lado del cliente. Puedes por ejemplo traer los resultados directamnte ordenados ascendentemente y aplicar la función *reserse* de javascript para darle directamente la vuelta a tu resultado, así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#cambiar').click(function(){
      var select = $('select');
      var options = select.children();
      select.html(options.get().reverse());
      var newoptions = select.children();
      newoptions.first().prop('selected', true);
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="cambiar" value="click">
```